# cpu load and nfs performance

Tags: linux-networking, nfs, storage-area-network, nfs4

I have an issue about nfs performance. The server is connected via an ISCSI connection TO a SAN. I have sometimes and more and more often load picks and client freezes.

I added RAM and try to optimize via different stuff :

1. sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
2. sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=10
3. increased to 256 the nfs number of process
4. checked the filesystems

I'm already using those nfs options rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,insecure_locks
I'm using nfsv4.
I have 2 ports in bond mode 0 round robin 1G/s each
the clients also got a 1G/s port

Comment: vm.dirty_background_ratio is 5% if the RAM. On a host with lot ot memory this can be quite a big number.  Try to use dirty_bytes and set it to the value which will be handled with you SAN infrastructure.

Comment: I have 2 G RAM and a lot of swap but the swap is never really used.